# Selectively modify single element of a list in a list-column (tidy solution)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to replace a single element of a list within a list-column with the value from another column:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a = list(list(number = 1, letter = "a"), list(number = 2, letter = "b")), b = c("c", "d"))
print(df)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   a          b    
#>   <list>     <chr>
#> 1 <list [2]> c    
#> 2 <list [2]> d
```

This is what the output should look like:

```
df2 <- tibble(a = list(list(number = 1, letter = "c"), list(number = 2, letter = "d")), b = c("c", "d"))
print(df2)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   a          b    
#>   <list>     <chr>
#> 1 <list [2]> c    
#> 2 <list [2]> d
```

I was able to use a for loop and confusing subsetting syntax, but I am wondering if there is a tidy function or more elegant way to accomplish my goal:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$a[[i]]$letter <- df$b[[i]]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a base R approach using `mapply` by changing values in `letter` element of every list from the corresponding `b` element.

```
df$a <- mapply(function(x, y) {x['letter'] <- y;list(x)}, df$a, df$b)

df$a
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$number
#[1] 1

#[[1]]$letter
#[1] "c"


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$number
#[1] 2

#[[2]]$letter
#[1] "d"
```

---

If you are interested in the `tidyverse` approach we could use the same logic using `map2`

```
library(tidyverse)

df$a <- map2(df$a, df$b, function(x, y) {x['letter'] <- y;x})
```

---

Or using a different approach using `lapply`

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(x) {
        df$a[[x]]['letter'] <- df$b[x]
        df[x, ]
}))
```

Comment: Could you explain why it is necessary to add list(x) after the assignment statement? I tried it without the list(x) and apparently it replaces the whole list with the variable, but I am not sure how adding list(x) corrects this problem.

Comment: @hlinee it will return the object which is last in `mapply` call. So if you don't return `list(x)` it will return only the modified `x['letter']` part and will ignore the remaining part of list which is `number` in this case.